# use javascript to push into javascript "members" object

Tags: javascript, push

I am trying to push data into a "members" object. This addition doesn't have to be permanent! But my code string doesn't work, although it looks (to me) like it should work fine. Can anyone please tell me why the push below doesn't work?

```
<script>
var members = [ 
{ "Class": "B", "Rating": "1776", "ID": "12537964", "Name": "Smith, John", "Expires": "2018.10.18" }, 
{ "Class": "C", "Rating": "1500", "ID": "12210580", "Name": "Jones, Jim", "Expires": "2019.01.12" }, 
{ "Class": "B", "Rating": "1759", "ID": "10117780", "Name": "Williams, Paula", "Expires": "2018.09.12" }
]
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id = "newMember" class="pure-form" method = ""> 
<fieldset> 

<label for="mem-name">Last, First name:</label> <input type="text" id = "mem-name" /> 
<label for="mem-expires">Membership:</label> <input type="text" id = "mem-expires" /> <br /> 
<label for="mem-rating">Rating:</label> <input type="text" id = "mem-rating" /> 
<label for="mem-ID">ID:</label> <input type="text" id = "mem-ID" /> 
<label for="mem-class">Class:</label> <input type="text" id = "mem-class" /> 

<button type="button" id="addPlayer" style="margin-left:2rem;"  onclick="validateForm()">add new player</button> 
<button type="reset">reset form</button> 

</fieldset> 

</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script> 

function validateForm() { 

var memName = document.getElementById('mem-name').value; 
var memExpires = document.getElementById('mem-expires').value; 
var memRating = document.getElementById('mem-rating').value; 
var memID = document.getElementById('mem-ID').value; 
var memClass = document.getElementById('mem-class').value; 

if (memName == "") { 
alert("Name must be filled out"); 
return false; 
}

//The line below doesn't work:

members.push({Name: "memName", Expires: "memExpires", Rating: "memRating", ID: "memID", Class: "memClass"});

} 

</script>
```

Comment: You want to place the quotes just swapped. `'Name'` but `memName` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing the strings, but you've to use variables instead. Instead of this:

```
members.push({Name: "memName", Expires: "memExpires", Rating: "memRating", ID: "memID", Class: "memClass"});
```

do this:

```
members.push({Name: memName, Expires: memExpires, Rating: memRating, ID: memID, Class: memClass});
```

For example `"memName"` is a string which has `memName` in it, whereas if you want the value of the text input, which you're storing in a variable named `memName`, you need to unwrap the value from double quotes.